# How to get result from two queries in same output window?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need output from the below two queries simultaneously in one output window.

**QUERY 1**

```
SELECT C.SERVICENAME, C.SERVICEID , B.SOAPIN, B.SOAPOUT, A.TIMESTAMP
FROM Schema1.LG_LOGENTRIES A, Schema1.LG_SOAPREQUESTS B, Schema1.CFG_SOAPSERVICES C
WHERE B.SERVICEID =C.SERVICEID AND 
C.SERVICENAME <>'UploadAndPrepareDocumentEx1__sdweb_services_preload' AND
A.ID=B.LOGENTRYID AND B.TIMESTAMP BETWEEN TO_DATE('02/01/2018 11:55:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
AND TO_DATE('02/01/2018 12:03:59','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND A.USERID IN (SELECT ID FROM Schema1.CFG_USERS 
WHERE NAME=UPPER(TO_CHAR('CGBXGVSG')));
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT B.JSONIN, B.JSONOUT,  A.TIMESTAMP, B.EVENT_MESSAGE, A.PROCESSID, A.status, A.SERVERNAME
FROM Schema1.LG_LOGENTRIES A, Schema1.LG_EVENT B
WHERE B.EVENT_MESSAGE NOT IN ('getFileImage','submitBase64','loadDocumentToSign','getRefData') AND
A.ID=B.LOG_ENTRYID AND B.TIMESTAMP BETWEEN TO_DATE('31/12/2017 13:43:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
AND TO_DATE('31/12/2017 13:53:59','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND A.USERID IN (SELECT ID FROM Schema1.CFG_USERS 
WHERE NAME=UPPER(TO_CHAR('CTHX8Y2G')));
```

Comment: Since the elements of both queries look unrelated to each other, I suggest  you could spool the output from both queries into a single file using SQL* Plus. If you do have any other relation that's not self-evident, you could let us know.

Comment: If you are using RapidSQL you can select both queries and run simultaneously, the result will be shown in the same window

Answer (score 1):

UNION might be one option, but you'll have to

- uniform both column lists (i.e. they have to return the same number of columns which have to be of the same data type), which means that you'd have to add certain NULL columns to both queries
- include additional identifier so that you'd know which SELECT returned which values

If you wanted to have them side-by-side, huh, that's not that easy. Thinking loudly: you'd have to have a column that joins those values. Those SELECTs would be inline views. You'd use an aggregate function (such as MAX) along with a DECODE (or CASE) to select values from both queries. Shortly: too much pain.

Now, why do you want to do that? What's wrong with two separate windows, placed side by side?

**[EDIT]** Showing example of how UNION might look like

```
select c.servicename, c.serviceid, b.soapin, b.soapout, a.timestamp, to_char(null), to_char(null), to_char(null)  , to_number(null), to_char(null), to_char(null)
from ... the rest of your 1st query
union
select null         , null       , null    , null     , a.timestamp, b.jsonin     , b.jsonout    , b.event_message, a.processid    , a.status     , a.servername 
from ... the rest of your 2nd query
```

Comment: Thanks for effort in issue.
I need both the result in one window because both queries fetch the log for the same action. I want the result to be sort wrt timestamp

Comment: So, that would be UNION, I presume.

Comment: Can you help me out in that case too, as I am not able to get that

Comment: I edited my message, showing how it might look like. I tried to put the same columns one under another so that you'd easier see the idea (and that will force you to scroll far right; sorry about that). As I don't know data types of those columns, I used TO_CHAR(NULL) and TO_NUMBER(NULL) - you'll have to fix that, most probably.

Comment: Oh, yes - another point: can you not join those two queries into a single one? Basically, you'd have to include LG_EVENT from 2nd query into the 1st one and join it properly with other tables.

Answer (score 1):

Run with F5 - you'll get both queries' output in the script panel.

I talk about how this differs [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/06/running-multiple-queries-in-oracle-sql-developer/)

[image: script output when running more than 1 statement with F5]

Comment: Right; that's something like executing two consecutive SELECT statements in SQLPlus, isn't it? Hopefully, that's what the OP is looking for. I just didn't understand it that way.

Comment: pretty much exactly like what you said, running statements consecutively in SQL*Plus

Comment: That,s a great stuff to know. But I need to have both the result in one Grid

Comment: Then please amend your question so that's clear. And mark the answer above CORRECT. The only way to do what you want is to run it as a SINGLE QUERY and you'll want to do what probably with a UNION. Or if the data is related, consider a simple JOIN.